# YII friendly SEO url

Tags: php, yii

I am struggling with this problem and not found any suitable answer.

I want *my_site/user/1* to become *my_site/user/user_name*

My urlManager looks like this:

```
'urlManager' => array(
  'urlFormat' => 'path',
  'rules' => array(
    'user/<username:\w+>'=>'user/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
  ),
  'showScriptName' => false,
),
```

User Controller:

```
public function actionView($username)
{
  $this->render('view', array(
    'model' => $this->loadModel($username),
  ));
}
```

When i hit /user/admin it redirects me to actionView not to the actionAdmin from my controller and i have multiple such actions like create, delete and so on. 
How can i avoid this? Is there an alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: In the URL manager the 1st value is user/<username> any user action will default back to that action. I would change the user part of the URL to manage-user or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The urlManager try's to match the url to a controller and action.
the 1st part of

```
'user/<username:\w+>'=>'user/view',
```

has matched to the user controller and the next part it looking for any string that consists of words, then sent the user to user/view

I recommend changing `user/<username>` to `manage-user/<username>` or `my-account/<username>`, something like that.

Comment: And you suggest to create another controller ManageUserController or MyAccountController?

Comment: No just change the 1st part of user/<username> to any link you would like /<username> then type that in the browser URL.
the 1st part is the match the 2nd part is where to send the user